# C# directly to machine language

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I'm looking for a tool that gives me the ability to write code in C # and compiling the binary file can be opened and translated directly into machine language, I mean he did not have the dependency on Framework ..

I heard about C # Parser, I wanted to know what it is and whether it gives me this ability

Thank you,
Oriel.

Answer (score 1):

A parser will only give you a parse tree, not machine code.

As far as I know, there is no such compiler. In a large because it would need to also compile any part of the BCL that you use as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think mono supports allows you to somehow deploy the runtime with your program. It also has an ahead-of-time compilation feature. But I haven't tried either, so I don't know if there are any problems with that, and if it works on windows.

Mono uses such features on iOS where you can't/aren't allowed to use a jitter.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a Linux box, and you're code isn't tied to specific MS applications, you could try compiling to BCL that way using MONO.  I remember doing that with C++ to M4 back in college, but that's ages ago.